# How can I combine several PDFs so that the first page of each PDF has an odd page number?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I combine several PDFs with Adobe Acrobat Pro XI:

[image]

How can I combine several PDFs so that the first page of each PDF has an odd page number? (e.g. by inserting a blank page if needed at the end of PDFs that have an odd number of pages)

I didn't see anything in the options:

[image]

Comment: Simplest way would be to create a PDF that is a blank page, then do a batch process on each file, inserting that same blank page in the same location ( after/before page 1 )

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for an automated solution:manually  inserting blank pages when needed is a bit tedious if many documents to combine :)

Comment: It wouldn't be manual.  You would perform a batch process on every pdf file in a location.  Adobe has this ability.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I had missed it. Is it possible to condition the insertion of the blank page on the parity of the number of pages of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PDFsam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam):

- gratis
- runs on Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X and Linux
- portable version available (at least on Windows)
- can add a blank page after each merged document if the document has an odd number of pages

[image]